# How to pretty print Scheme code in Emacs?

Tags: scheme, pretty-print

I would like to format Scheme code inside Emacs, I'm developing Scheme interpreter and my formatter don't work quite right, so while I'm working on syntax-rules macro I would like to pretty print the code I'm working on, without the need right not to fix my formatter.

The code is expansion of SRFI-197 that I'm try to debug and fix (fix my syntax-rules implementation since the code in SRFI-197 is correct).

Just for completeness here is the code I'm trying to format:

```
(let () (define-syntax %chain (syntax-rules …₂ (placeholder ellipsis) ((_ () () () ((var) …₂) () (step …₂ last-step)) (let* ((var step) …₂) last-step)) ((_ () () () (vars …₂) () (step …₂ last-step)) (let*-values ((vars step) …₂) last-step)) ((_ () () () out-vars (step . in-steps) out-steps) (%chain step () () out-vars in-steps out-steps)) ((_ () step () (out-vars …₂) in-steps (out-steps …₂)) (%chain () () () (out-vars …₂ ignored) in-steps (out-steps …₂ step))) ((_ () step vars (out-vars …₂) in-steps (out-steps …₂)) (%chain () () () (out-vars …₂ vars) in-steps (out-steps …₂ step))) ((_ (placeholder ellipsis) (step …₂) () (out-vars …₂) in-steps (out-steps …₂)) (%chain () () () (out-vars …₂ chain-rest-var) in-steps (out-steps …₂ (apply step …₂ chain-rest-var)))) ((_ (placeholder ellipsis) (step …₂) (vars …₂) (out-vars …₂) in-steps (out-steps …₂)) (%chain () () () (out-vars …₂ (vars …₂ . chain-rest-var)) in-steps (out-steps …₂ (apply step …₂ chain-rest-var)))) ((_ (placeholder ellipsis . rest) . _) (syntax-error _ ... can only be used as a final argument)) ((_ (placeholder . in-step) (out-step …₂) (vars …₂) . rest) (%chain in-step (out-step …₂ chain-var) (vars …₂ chain-var) . rest)) ((_ (x . in-step) (out-step …₂) . rest) (%chain in-step (out-step …₂ x) . rest)))) (%chain (map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) _) () () () ((filter odd? _) (fold * 1 _)) (initial-value)))
```